# Induction when not dealing with Sigma notation

Tags: induction

How do you prove $4^n > 3^n + 2^n$ using induction?
Base case would be when $n = 2$, $16 > 13$.
Then assume $n = k$ so that $4^k > 3^k + 2^k$.
Then let $n = k + 1$ so that $4^{k+1} > 3^{k+1} + 2^{k+1}$
But then what?  What am I trying to match up so that this can be proven by induction?

Answer (score 4):

If $\displaystyle4^k>3^k+2^k,$

$$4^{k+1}=4\cdot4^k>4(3^k+2^k)=4\cdot3^k+4\cdot2^k>3\cdot3^k+2\cdot2^k$$